# In Unity, all "O" are showing up as "V"

Tags: fonts

Since today, in Ubuntu 12.10 running Unity, my font has been doing something strange.

The `O` characters are showing up as `V`. See the graphics below. For example, the desktop folder on this file open dialog is spelled as `Desktvp`.

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you just installed Ubuntu, or this begin to happen from one instance to the next one? Did you get the same issue using a terminal? Also, have you tried with [this suggestion](http://askubuntu.com/a/36666/62483)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fonts can become corrupted.

Try re-installing `ttf-ubuntu-font-family` and then rebooting.

To re-install use [Synaptic](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic) [image: Install synaptic] or run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ttf-ubuntu-font-family
```