# display anomaly - any ideas

Tags: 11.04, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Font corruption: lines through characters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29626/font-corruption-lines-through-characters)

ubuntu 11.04 shows this kind of white pixels across text.  [image: display-anomaly] 
Any ideas what they are caused by? and what to do about it? i'm using an acer aspire 1604Z laptop.

Comment: __Update__:
This question is dealing with the same issue ( http://askubuntu.com/questions/29626/font-corruption-lines-through-characters ) and the answer worked for me.