# Text is cut out

Tags: 12.04, display, intel-graphics, fonts

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 desktop on my PC. Everything is OK, but when I use Firefox, Terminal. The text is cut out, I can fix it by zooming in/out.

This is the output when I run `lspci | grep vga`.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
```

So how can I fix it?

This is the image showing the problem (notice the text on the tags, for example, specially the 'o' character):

[image: no zoom in]

After I zoom in, it looks better:

[image: zoom in]

Edit: Well, I followed Vanni' post in [Font corruption: lines through characters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29626/font-corruption-lines-through-characters?rq=1). Now, everything is OK, the text isn't cut out. Thanks